# Why is this something does Bash say that modavar command even tho i aliased it

Tags: bash

Note this is sourced, so this is not a shell script.

I am not asking for how to enable alias in noninteractive shell. I did this: `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

The Bash version is 5.1.4.

How to recreate:

Create a file named "p":

```
linky(){
comdll="cat"
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias modavar="$comdll"
echo "$argin" | modavar #| getlinks "$argin" | sort -u

}
```

Then run

```
echo "source p ; linky https://duckduckgo.com" | bash --norc
```

Expected output:

```
https://duckduckgo.com
```

Actual output:

```
p: line 5: modavar: command not found
```

When I run this once it give me

```
linky(){ alias jkl=echo\ hel; jkl; }
linky
bash: jkl: command not found
```

But if I do this,

```
linky(){ alias jkl=echo\ hel; jkl; }
linky
linky(){ alias jkl=echo\ hel; jkl; }
linky
```

It gives me

```
hel
```

What is happening?

Comment: You showed your code in your good way, but I don't understand the question on the level of English language (what does _to recate put in_  mean, and the title of the question).  However,  I can see that you are using a variable `argin`, which you never set - this is conspicuous. Further, I would also use the option `-x` in your bash command, as long as you are not done with debugging yet.

Comment: to redo or remake the problem i have selvar reading disablbilitys

Comment: With the program as you have posted it, I would expect that you just get an empty line (single newline character) as output. Perhaps you could also explain what output you get.

Comment: I understand that this is difficult, and it is absolutely brave to turn to **programming** when having reading problems. Sadly, I also don't understand _redo the problem_. Perhaps it's best if you describe what output you expect from your program, and which output you actually see.  Also, remove the commented-out part of your code, as it is distracting and does not help at the moment. You can put it back in later, after having solved the basic problem.

Comment: @Inee_94 : What happens if you move the alias definition to **before** the function definition? aliases ar not function-local anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define the alias inside a function and use it there. Consider these examples:

```
alias foo=cat
ffoo() {
  echo abc|foo
}
fbar() {
  alias bar=cat
  echo abc|bar
}
ffoo  #->prints abc
fbar  #->prints command not found
```